# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32crypt'

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm trying to run a Python module for a school project and I am getting this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32crypt'` at line `import win32crypt`.

I've search the website for solution and encountered a post that states pywin32 is required. So I installed it with pip. I also tried installing pypiwin32. None of these installs worked. Now I've tried Dependency Walker to see if there are any dependencies missing and I see at least 100 DLLs that are. How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 3):

`win32cryrpt` is a part of the Windows Extensions for Python or `pywin32`. It is a wrapper around the Windows crypto API. It doesn't make sense to try and install it without `pywin32` and if your install of that has failed then that is the problem you have to solve.

Please try `pip install pypiwin32` again, being sure to execute it in the correct folder, which is the `Scripts` subfolder of the Python environment you want to install it in. You may have more than one Python installation without realizing it, and if you run `pip` from outside that folder, you may get a different instance of `pip`. The standard location for Python installations is `C:\Program Files\Python3x`. If the `pip` install doesn't complete as expected then edit your question to include the messages from the failed install. *Did not work* isn't enough to go on.

Comment: This does not work. Install did not visibly fail. No errors except the one in the OP.